# Magento Checkout add Error Message

Tags: magento, redirect, checkout

within the checkout process I have the problem that I can't add an error message and 'redirect' to a section within the checkout.

If I use

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError
```

I can add a Error message which will be shown **after reload**. But I can't seem to find a solution to add an error message or JS alert which is shown either before or after the 'redirect' to a section.

Underneath is my current code, which I tried to solve the problem.

Andy help is appreciated.

```
if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
                $result['redirect']=Mage::getUrl('customer/account/edit/'); 
            } else {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'billing';
                $result['error']= false;
                $result['message'] = addError($this->__('test'));
            }
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return ;
```

Comment: on which checkout step you want the message?

Comment: The code above is on the step where the customer picks the payment mean. If the customer did not set his birthday and picks 'check mo' it should switch back to the step where the personal data is entered and the message should appear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using ajax login, in this case in your ajax success action, you need to check if there is an error msg, if yes, append div using jquery or whichever library you are using dynamically to dom.

There is no way you can get error msges in ajax using default addError or addSuccess

Comment: The problem isn't the check for logged in or not. The problem I have is that I can't set the section and trigger a message to appear.

it works fine on redirect, but not after 'goto_section'